# Jupyter Notebook nbextension Table of Contents (2) hidden behind top panel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I'm using Jupyter Notebook nbextension Table of Contents (2).

Part of the contents are hidden behind the top panel.
How do I config it to make it display properly?
[image]

I tried

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.maintoolbar { margin-top: 100px; }</style>"))
```

But it moves my toolbar up, rather than move the ToC down.
[image]

Comment: Hello same probleme here 
i am on windows 11 and i had many probleme to install nbextention 

Did you find any solution pls ?

Comment: I also start having an issue after I've got new PC and made fresh installation of all python packages including the notebook and extensions. To me it looks like it is an issue with the newer version of the extension. Did anyone tried to downgrade it in some way?

Answer (score 4):

I found that when I slightly drag down the table of content on the LHS it solves this issue. It will still appear this way every time the notebook is loaded initially.

Answer (score 1):

Until this issue is resolved, here are some workarounds to fix notebook nbextension toc2 bad position.

Option 1:
Copy and run the following code in a notebook cell ([Reference](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1651#issue-1878476788)).

```py
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:83%; align: left; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>#toc-wrapper{ position: relative; width: 20%; top: 130px; left: 0px; }</style>"))
```

Option 2:
Alternatively, click and drag anywhere in the toc sidebar area ([Reference](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1629#issuecomment-1485372687), also mentioned in other answer).